# How to create javascript to execute as a rule condition in Alfresco Share

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm new to Alfresco and especially to Javascript.

I have a bunch of custom model forms related to the type of the document that is being uploaded and each of them has 4 properties: ***client.name, doc.subtype, doc.year, doc.month***.

I need few scripts to apply as 'folder rules' which programmatically have to redistribute every file received and uploaded to my *INBOX* folder.

```
#1 script:
```

To be applied on ***INBOX*** folder, has to check if already exists a site with the name of 'client.name' property and has to rename the uploaded file to ***'client.name + custom-model-name + doc.month + doc.year'*** and move it . If the site does not exist yet, it has to create it and then move the respective file.

```
#2 Script:
```

To be applied on ***client.name*** created folder, will receive the corresponding renamed file and check if already exists a folder with the name of the ***'custom-model-name'*** and then move it accordingly. If the folder does not exist yet, it has to create and then move it to the created folder.

```
#3 Script:
```

To be applied on ***'custom-model-name'*** created folder, will receive the corresponding renamed file and check if already exists a folder with the name of the ***doc.subtype*** property and then move it accordingly. If the folder does not exist yet, it has to create and then move it to the created folder.

```
#4 Script:
```

To be applied on ***doc.subtype*** created folder, will receive the corresponding renamed file and check if already exists a folder with the name of the ***doc.year*** property and then move it accordingly. If the folder does not exist yet, it has to create and then move it to the created folder.

```
#5 and last script:
```

To be applied on ***doc.year*** created folder, will receive the corresponding renamed file and check if already exists a folder with the name of the ***doc.month*** property and then move it accordingly. If the folder does not exist yet, it has to create and then move it to the created folder.

---

*Below is the desired tree structure of my folders:*

```
├─INBOX
├───client.name1
│   ├───custom-model-name1
|   |     └──doc.subtype1
|   |     |    └──doc.year
|   |     |         └──doc.month  
|   |     └──doc.subtype2
|   |          └──doc.year
|   |               └──doc.month  
│   ├───custom-model-name2
|   |     └───doc.subtype3
|   |         └───doc.year
|   |              └───doc.month
├───client.name2
│   ├───custom-model-name1
|   |     └──doc.subtype1
|   |     |    └──doc.year
|   |     |         └──doc.month  
|   |     └──doc.subtype2
|   |          └──doc.year
|   |               └──doc.month  
│   ├───custom-model-name2
|   |     └───doc.subtype3
|   |         └───doc.year
|   |              └───doc.month

and so on
```

Hopefully I made myself clear.

PS: I know that I might get this done by creating the default rules in each folder. However, I won't be able this way to test whether the folders are already created or not.

Any help will be much appreciated. Regards.

Comment: And why not? You just use the JS API and check if the folder exists with something like this: 

`var folder = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/cm:SomeFolder/*\" +TYPE:\"cm:folder\"");

if (folder null || folder.length == 0) { ... }else{ ... }`

Also you want to check this guide http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html which has all the info to actually create your scripts (which is a fairly simple task), and here http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html you'll find all about the Alfresco JS API

Comment: Hi @Alch3mi5t! Thanks for your hint. I forgot to mention that those properties are in the majority aspects related to month and year the document refers to.

All of my properties are aspects related to constraints (client, subtype, year, month). 

Regarding the first step of my condition, I wonder how do I work with those aspects for instance, in this case 

var newfolder = userhome.createFolder("{Client.name}" , "st:site")

How do I replace this {Client.name} to refer to my property(aspect) client?

Thanks

Comment: I just read and by creating sites through that way it won't be fully accessible/useful, right?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand your comment, but if you want to be able to add properties/aspects to your node (content or folder, it really doesn't matter), just use this: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-addAspect.html, and you can update your property like this: `document.properties["my:property"] = "new value";
document.save();` once you've added the aspect that contains it.

Comment: Hey @Alch3mi5t! How do I work with declared vars onto the search query? For example, 
var client_folder = document.properties["ext1:prop1_aspect_client"].
Then var folder = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/{the client_folder var I declared}/*\" +TYPE:\"cm:folder\""); 
Thanks man.

Comment: it's as normal as it can get with JS. Just declare a var (eg. client_folder), then reuse it in the query: `var folder = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/" + client_folder + "/*\" +TYPE:\"cm:folder\"");` That of course if your client_folder value (which is a node property as far as I can see), corresponds to the actual site name where you're searching against (in "sites" PATH). Also, I'm not entirely sure of the brackets positioning, you might have to do some debug on that as well. Is that what you're aiming for?